# How do I fill an area with faces lined up in a grid?

Tags: modeling

I need to change these polygons into a mesh with the same amounts of edges going the opposite way so I can end up with a mesh that I can curve edges upward and indent the heel and ball of foot area downward, sort of making it look ergonomic. Subdivide adds an diagonal edge but also vastly increases the edges where I already have enough. Suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you have a hammer, every problem looks like a nail.  My hammer is python.  Maybe I'll be able to bang out a solution.

Comment: @MutantBob No need, there's already a tool for it :) OP: select the verticies you want to cut, and press "J". You could also use the knife tool "K". If that works I'll write up an answer.

Comment: I'd try handling that by deleting all the top faces and using grid fill. It With some tweaking it should give you the edges you need.

Comment: @Marc Did you try the knife tool?

Comment: No, no knife tool yet. I don't know how to use it but I'll try now. (blend file added)  UPDATE: Looks like the knife tool will work. I just want the lazy way out and not have to cut each new edge one by one. lol. but it looks like I have too. Thanks

Comment: Just so you know, I tried my "J" trick and it worked. I'm wrote up an answer. I also threw in how to do it with the knife tool.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Delete all of the top faces.

[image]

Select the top loop edge ring.

[image]

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> and select **Grid Fill** (or use the menu: Mesh->Faces->Grid Fill)

[image]

, playing with the settings until you find a result that you like:

[image]

**NOTE:**  For this to work you need a continuous loop with an **Even** number of vertices. An Odd number of vertices will report a "*must select two edge loops*" error.

Comment: Brilliant!!!  thx!

Comment: Man,  I should have turned my comment into an answer

Comment: @GiantCowFilms sorry I didn't read the comments...

Comment: @cegaton No, my fault - I was being to lazy.

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised that worked. In my experience you have to carefully select certain edge loops evenly to get grid fill to work...

Comment: @TARDISMaker thanks for pointing that out. See edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Select the two virticies you want to make an edge between and press <kbd>J</kbd>.

[image]

[image]

You can also use the knife tool. Press <kbd>K</kbd> and click on the two vertices you want to bridge,

[image]

And press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: oops, Yep, you're right. It does work. So does the knife tool. I just wanted a way to do them all at once with a click or two. :) Thanks

Comment: Ah... Well maybe @MutantBob can come up with a python solution for you :)