# I'm looking for an addon to fill faster open/broken areas with vertices

Tags: modeling, add-on, vertices

I'm looking for an addon to fill fast and simmetrically some area that needs to be closed with vertices. Doing it manually it takes a lot of time. Check the attached screenshot. thanks.

[image]

I tried to do what's explained in the duplicate question,but it didn't solved my problem. For example,I tried to select two or more edge loops with `Alt + Shift + RMB` and then connect them with `W > Bridge`,but this is what happened :

[image: 1]

and this :

[image]

and i tried also activating the `F2 addon` and then pressing the `F key` :

[image]

none of these solutions worked for me...

errata corrige : by pressing `CTRL F` and then `grid fill` worked for me...thanks.

Comment: [GridFill](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#grid-fill) should handle with that. Somewhat related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45894/how-do-i-fill-an-area-with-faces-lined-up-in-a-grid

Comment: I have edited the question. Please reload the web page..it seems that none of the solutions explained on the duplicated question worked for me...

Comment: errata corrige : the option CTRL F and then grid fill worked for me...thanks.